# Image as ByteArray in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, adobe, arrays

I would like to be able to move images into and out of Flex by converting back and forth between ByteArrays. I've been having some trouble with this, so I designed a simple test program, and even that I can't get to work. Here's the code I'm trying right now:

```
protected function button3_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler2);
loader.load(new URLRequest("file:///c:/win.jpg"));
}

private function loaderCompleteHandler2(event:Event):void
{
var loader:Loader = (event.target as LoaderInfo).loader;
var bmp:Bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);
image1.source = bmp;
myBmpData = bmp.bitmapData;
myByteArray = bmp.bitmapData.getPixels(myBmpData.rect);
}

protected function button4_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(myByteArray);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderCompleteHandler);  
}

private function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
var loader:Loader = (event.target as LoaderInfo).loader;
var bmp:Bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);
image1.source = bmp;
}
```

So far the process follows top to bottom: Click button 3, image displays, everything is going well. Click button 4, and I get "Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type." after the line "loader.loadBytes(myByeArray);" in the function button4_clickHandler. As far as I can tell I'm using everything as intended. I would really appreciate any suggestions to get me moving in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following code:

```
 var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("/path/to/image"));
 l.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
 l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

 private function loaded(event:Event):void
 {
     var ba:ByteArray = event.currentTarget.data as ByteArray;

     b64Img.source = Base64.encode(ba); 
 }
```

The **b64Img** object that i set the *source* property on is a Base64Image which is a part of the great [FlexLib](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/) project. So, in effect, what you are doing is the following:

- Loading in an image as a binary stream
- Base64 encoding the bytes
- Displaying it on the screen

Cheers

Comment: By the way, i'm using JP Auclair's Base64 class:
http://jpauclair.net/2010/01/09/base64-optimized-as3-lib/

Comment: the solution works well, but I encounter another problem: 1.get the byteArray from an exist image 2.deal with the byteArray(compress or change the byteArray) and return, then I want show a new Image, which use the new byteArray, b64Img.source = Base64.encode(newBuyeArray), the problem is the image can't show

Answer (score 0):

Danny Kopping's solution above should work, and URLLoader should perform better than Loader.load().

But then, the use of Base64Image is IMHO not optimal. Internally, Base64Image uses Loader.loadBytes & decodes the Base64 beforehand -  so effectively, there is an encode to Base64 followed by a decode.

I suggest simply using the loadBytes method of Loader like this:

```
private function loaded(event:Event):void
{
  var loader:Loader = new Loader();
  loader.loadBytes(event.currentTarget.data as ByteArray);     
}
```

I don't know of a way that would avoid using Loader altogether.